# Plotting polygons in R when y range is character vector

Tags: r, polygons

I have some plotting code I've used before with data that is all numeric or integer. Now I have similar data except one column is character data, which ?polygon says I can use.  I've been wrestling with this and can't solve the errors I'm getting.  Help, please!

My data is:

```
Dem.plotting <- data.frame(
  Group=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  Year=c("2012", "Dem", "Non-dem", "2012", "Dem", "Non-dem", "2012", 
          "Dem", "Non-dem"),
  minGDP=c(17.1, 17.3, 20.2, 19.8, 20.3, 21.7, 20.7, 21.7, 22.6),
  maxGDP=c(19.4, 20.3, 21.5, 20.5, 21.3, 21.9, 21.4, 22.5, 22.3),
  Data=data.frame(Group, Year, minGDP, maxGDP))
```

This is the code I've used successfully before but isn't working now:

```
yrange = range(Dem.plotting$Year)
xrange = range(Dem.plotting[,3:4])
plot(Year~minGDP,data=Dem.plotting,type="n",xlab="Log(GDP)",ylab="Year",
     ylim=yrange,xlim=xrange)
dens = c(NA,20,40,NA,20,40,NA,20)
ang = rep(45,times=8)
fillcol = c("white","gray","gray","black","black","black","white","gray")
for (i in 1:nrow(Dem.plotting)){
  with(Dem.plotting[i,],polygon(x=c(minGDP,maxGDP,maxGDP,minGDP),
                        y=c(Year+0.25,Year+0.25,Year-0.25,Year-0.25),
                        density=dens[Group],ang=ang,
                        col=fillcol[Group],
                        border="black"
 )
 )
}
```

I get the following error from trying to set up the empty plot:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value
In addition: Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

So R doesn't like having the character vector for 'Year', and I don't know how to fix that, and then this error is generated when trying to plot the polygons:

```
Error in Year + 0.25 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I understand that it doesn't like that 'Year' is character, and not numeric, but I thought you could plot polygons using character data for vertices?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can use character arguments to `polygon()`. I'm not sure where you got that impression from in the help file.

Comment: shoot.  I think you're right.  You can use character objects in range, but you're right, it doesn't say it for polygon.

Comment: What kind of result would you expect? Stepping through your code, the first error is of course thrown by `range(Dem.plotting$Year)`. What would the range of a character variable (that happens to contain the string "2012") be?

Comment: I figured it would be like 'unique' and be the set of unique strings in the range.